# PHP/MySQL game server

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

This is the current logic behind my game engine:

1. User logs in
2. User wants to start a new game and enters lobby
3. Looks for a game with a space free. (There will be 20 max, 10 min users per game. Once a min of 10, count down starts until the start of the game)
4. When the user enters a game, the game database entry is updated with the user's ID.
5. Deliver payload to user (info for the game; for example, questions)
6. User completes game and sends result to the server
7. Server checks results, works out who has the 1st, 2nd and 3rd highest score. Adds points to the user database entry, send's results back to all clients (leaderboard)
8. Game room is destroyed.

This will be done via PHP/MySQL with the clients accessing via JSON. I'm confused how to do step 2 and 3 with these technologies. Specifically, how do I poll for a room to have met the requirements, i.e 20 max, 10 min users. If more than 10 users for say 10 seconds then start start the or if 20 max then start the game?

I'm trying to think of the logic but struggling.

EDIT: I think that's a little unfair closing this question. I'm not asking for people to code the thing for me, i'm asking for advice on the logic used.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you just can't expect anyone to think of some code for you. If you are having problems with your code, we can help out. Creating code from scratch just will not do.

Comment: @Topener: I don't think they were asking for someone to do their code for them, but just the general steps one would take to achieve those steps they were having problems with.

Comment: Correct, i'm not after code. Just idea's for logic.

Comment: Retagged to include algorithm.

Comment: @icktoofay ok clear! I would've flagged if I was 100% certain, but I was not! Thanks for clearing it up. Unfortunately I do not have an answer.

Comment: I agree; I think it was incorrect to close it as well. I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a game logic loop that runs independently on the server, (started by cron for example), which monitors your game rooms (as that's basically as what a player inviting other players can be seen).

If then the room is full enough (or completely filled) with players, it updates the according row in the database to indicate the game has started, and saves at which time that was exactly.

Now the client keeps polling a script, say, once a second, to see whether the game in his room has started and how many milliseconds that was ago. If it's started, the countdown begins. You might have to skip displaying the "10" but start at "9" (or lower even), for when a client receives the answer to its poll a second or more later after the game has started, and all clients will be synchronized.

Comment: Every second is too much and unnecessary.  At the most frequent, I'd say 5 seconds, but realistically 10.

Comment: i need to make this as scalable as possible. I'm starting to think if PHP/MySQL are the right technologies for this.

Comment: Don't do premature optimalization. PHP and MySQL are as scalable as it gets, but it depends on the implementation for how scalable it will be.